# TW7ToolButton - add dropdown menu

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, tms

According to TMS, W7ToolButton1 can be used for displaying a dropdown menu. But I am failing to see how you can do that as it has no dropdown menu property. Only menu I can add is the popup menu which is not the same as the dropdown one.Someone knows how to add a dropdown menu to the button??? I can add a dropdown arrow to the button but its a mystery on how to make the popup menu show on clicking this arrow (assuming it functions this way) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TW7ToolButton does not appear to have an event for clicking on the split button arrow so this may be the best you can do with the current component version:

```
procedure TForm1.W7ToolButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  iPoint: TPoint;
begin
  iPoint := ClientToScreen(Point(W7ToolButton1.Left, W7ToolButton1.Top + W7ToolButton1.Height));
  PopupMenu1.Popup(iPoint.X, iPoint.Y);
end;
```

The menu will appear under the button just like a dropdown menu.

Comment: Yes, I suppose this is the only way to do this.Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with TMS, however, with regular button/speedbutton you could use something like:

```
PopupMenu1.Popup (Form1.Left + SpeedButton1.Left + SpeedButton1.Height, Form1.Top + SpeedButton1.Top + SpeedButton1.Width);
```

Comment: why not use `TWinControl.ClientToScreen` ?

Comment: For `TButton` there is the `bsSplitButton` value for `Style` property and `DropDownMenu` property in Delphi XE4, so none of this is needed. The same applies maybe even for Delphi 2009 in [`this Q&A`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2016890/960757). But still TMS may do it in a different way...

Comment: There's other components I can use (Raize - RzMenuToolbarButton1) but I am interested in the TMS one.